# Buying from Hasogas Gevul

Tags: halacha, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, transactions, business

If someone has a shop that the Rabanim say is hasogas gevul, but he refuses to close it, is it just a problem for the seller or is it also a problem for buying from there?

Comment: "Rabanim" which Rabanim ? are you talking about a City with a single community Bet Din or about a city that has several Batei Din ?

Comment: Are you asking if it's permitted to go against the psak or do you just mean to establish a case where there is no safek as to the status of the store ? assuming the latter...

Comment: When I lived in a certain community with this issue, the Rabbonim issued an announcement instructing everyone not to shop there.  That could have just been a practical way of giving their decision practical weight, but it was an instruction coming from the local Beis Din nonetheless.

Comment: @eramm, re "Are you asking if it's permitted to go against the psak or do you just mean to establish a case where there is no safek as to the status of the store ?" -- or a third possibility: the potential customer who has this _sh'ela_ follows a rabbi who's ruled that the storekeeper is _masig g'vul_.

Answer (score 3):

There is a concept in Halacha of not encouraging somebody to continue his evil ways.

For example: One may not buy from a thief, as this encourages him to continue stealing.

If this is a real case of Hasogas Gevul then buying from him encourages him to continue being Masig Gevul, and it should be forbidden.

Sample source from the Kitzur סימן קפב - הלכות גנבה וגזלה in סעיף ח:

> **אָסוּר לִקְנוֹת מֵהַגַנָּב אוֹ מֵהַגַּזְלָן אֶת הַחֵפֶץ שֶׁגָּנַב אוֹ גָזָל**. וְאֵין חִלּוּק בֵּין שֶׁהוּא יִשְֹרָאֵל אוֹ נָכְרִי, כִּי גַם הַנָּכְרִי נִצְטַוֶּה עַל אִסּוּר גְּנֵבָה וּגְזֵלָה אֲפִלּוּ מִנָּכְרִי חֲבֵרוֹ, וְהוּא מִשֶּׁבַע מִצְוֹת שֶׁנִּצְטַוּוּ עֲלֵיהֶם. **וְעָוֹן גָּדוֹל הוּא לִקְנוֹת מִן הַגַּנָּב אוֹ מִן הַגַּזְלָן, שֶׁהֲרֵי הוּא מַחֲזִיק יְדֵי עוֹבְרֵי עֲבֵרָה**. וְעַל זֶה נֶאֱמַר, חוֹלֵק עִם גַּנָּב שׂוֹנֵא נַפְשׁוֹ, **וְגוֹרֵם לַגַּנָּב שֶׁיִגְנוֹב עוֹד גַּם גְּנֵבוֹת אֲחֵרוֹת**, וְאִם לֹא יִמְצָא לוֹקֵחַ, לֹא יִגְנוֹב.‏

Comment: +1 That was exactly what I was going to post. Additional Source Rambam Laws of Gneivah Ch 5 Halacha 1 http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1088877/jewish/Genevah-Chapter-Five.htm